# Hosting Elasticsearch on AWS: {"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, npm, deployment, localhost

I am trying to host an Elasticsearch Application on an AWS Server. For this purpose I am using Elastic Enterprise Search. I configured the API connector as follows:

```
const connector = new AppSearchAPIConnector({
  searchKey: "search-gs7t3micqu41z1dsou1ccz95",
  engineName: "sentence-similarity",
  endpointBase: "http://ec2-18-159-135-25.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3002"
});
```

The application itself is running with npm under port 3000. I enabled both ports in the AWS Security Group.

After starting both Elastic Search and Enterprise Search, after `npm start` I can also connect to http://ec2-18-159-135-25.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000, so that works. However, once I make an API call over the application, I get the following error:

> POST
> http://ec2-18-159-135-25.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3002/api/as/v1/engines/sentence-similarity/search.json
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Moreover, when I type `curl http://localhost:3002/api/as/v1/engines/sentence-similarity/search.json` in the console, I get the following error:

> {"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}

Therefore I assume, that there is a problem with the connection to Elasticsearch. When I was hosting the application on my local machine, I never encountered this problem.

**My ideas, how to possibly fix the problem:**

- I had to reinstall Elastic Search and Enterprise Search on the AWS
  Server. Possibly, something with the authentification went wrong, and
  I cannot connect to my Elasticsearch engine.
- There are two `.yml` files, one for Elastic Search and one for Enterprise Search, which I can configure. Possibly, I have to adjust these, when I host the application not on my local machine.

In any case, I am a beginner in deployment and I need some help for the details. Thank you very much in advance!

**EDIT:**

After some more research, I believe I identified the problem. It seems like on the AWS server, there is sort of a new Elastic Enterprise instance established. That means, that there is no engine configured yet, which is why the API call fails. How can I connect to my existing engine instead of having to create a new one?

Comment: on the 3000 port the same behaviour?

Comment: no the 3000 port works fine

Comment: maybe there is misconfiguration for 3002, use 3000 or try to add another

Answer (score 1):

Well I have not used the AWS Elastic search but i can give some suggestions, check below urls,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-vpc.html#kibana-test
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWRo_JVgP_0

Also consider checking security groups.